# Javascript combine with my css to add an effect on imagechange

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change my images with `javascript` and add an `fade` effect.
This is my `css` for the fade effect:

```js
    var image=document.getElementById("image");
    var currentPos = 0;
    var images = ["foto1.jpg","foto2.jpg","foto3.jpg"]

    function volgendefoto() {
        if (++currentPos >= images.length) currentPos = 0;
        image.src = images[currentPos];

    }

    setInterval(volgendefoto, 4100);
```

```css
#map {
        height:1000px;
        width:1000px;
        background:black;
    }
    #overlay {
        z-index:2;
        background:white;
        height:1000px;
        width:1000px;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.1s;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.1s;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.1s;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.1s;
        transition: opacity 1s;
        margin-top:-1000px;
    
        transition-delay: 0.1s;
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    }
    #overlay:hover {
        opacity:.8;
        transition-delay: 0s;
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='map'>
        <img id="image" src="foto1.jpg">
        <div id='overlay'></div>
    
    </div>
```

It is for a school project where we are making a responsive website, so I am going to add this to that site.

Comment: Also add HTML code

Comment: image.id="map overlay" to add the IDs to your image. But you might want to consider using classes instead of IDs

Comment: Are we going to guess the HTML?

Comment: Since you use jQuery, you can use fadeIn() method.

Comment: i don't use jquery, if possible i only want to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

Tried your piece of code which gives fade-out effect for the image on hover.

```
[You can see the output below][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/cxLjLnu8/1/ "Output here"
```

Is this what you did and expected?

Which effect you are in need of fade-in
 or fade-out?
and 
do you need the effect on Hover or on sliding the images?